# Is there a way to have an item which can break SPECIFIC BLOCKS with SPECIFIC FACING?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know it's possible to make block breakable by items, but I wonder if I could make an item which can only break the specified blocks if they're facing a given direction.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. `CanDestroy" simply does not have that feature.

You could try using [raycasting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/362596/171580) to determine whether the player is looking at a block with the right block state or not and then give a shovel that can or can not break blocks, but that is very complicated and not fully reliable.

Comment: Although this is not the answer I hoped for, I'd still like to thank you for your time and for giving a new option(ray casting). Thank you very much.